# swift mailer php windows server

Tags: php, swiftmailer

i'm in trouble with sending email using swiftmailer on windows server.
everything works fine on linux but email can not be send on windows server (page execute and no error message display).
is there anything that has to be set up in php.ini 
here is my code:

..
    require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance();

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

 ->setSubject('...')

  ->setFrom(array($fromm => '..')) 

  ->setTo(array($fromm, $mail))

  ->setBody(
```

...

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you define an SMTP server for swiftmailer to use? it can't send mail without a local SMTA or a remote SMTP. Windows systems don't have those by default.

Comment: yes, i 've try to define smtp server for swiftmailer (and username and passw) but didn work..Could the problem be that Database is hosted in a different hosting account? Databse is hosted in linux server and web is hosted in windows server.

Comment: database shouldn't matter at all. you're just fetching an email address from the db, which is just text. still need to have a valid SMTP server for swift to connect to from the windows box to actually SEND that email.